# How do I access a tomcat 5.5 installation via localhost running on Virtual PC 2007?

Tags: tomcat, localhost, virtual-pc

I have a tomcat installation of 5.5 up and running on a Virtual PC with a fresh XP pro SP3.  Launching tomcat gives the standard messages:

> INFO: Find registry
>   server-registry.xml at classpath
>   resource Apr 12, 2010 11:43:44 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
>   start INFO: Server startup in 3576 ms

However, I cannot for the life of me connect to http://localhost:8080.  I've also tried http://127.0.0.1:8080 with no success.  This is on the virtual PC itself that I cannot connect to the server - I haven't bothered to try it on the host machine.

Can anyone provide any information on why this may be happening?  It's a fresh install of tomcat using Sun's JRE 5.0 (I know, EOL, technical requirements make me have to use 5.0 and not a newer JRE).

Comment: Did you install the default applications with it?  When you open a cmd prompt on the vm and telnet to localhost 8080 what happens?

Comment: I don't know what was supposed to happen with telnet, it just has an empty prompt.  All the defaults (host manager, manager) are there - just a fresh unzip from the Tomcat 5.5 download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently I downloaded a bad copy of Tomcat - it may happen from time to time.  If anyone else has this problem in the future, try re-downloading Tomcat and testing it on your host machine first - if it works there it will probably then work on the virtual PC.